# Making a simple script for counting which members of a set have appeared, and outputting probability of appearance of the remaining members

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, bash-functions

I am creating a simple bash script, but am relatively new to it. Hear me out and the easy (I hope) question will follow.

i need to make a script that will take input from the keyboard to know which member of the set has appeared in front of me, mark it or remove it from the set and send it to another, so that i can keep track of the probabilities for which set member will appear next. So i need to have a set for non revealed symbols/characters, and a separate set for the revealed ones. I want the script to keep a real time output going for the probability of each (non-revealed) set member to appear next.

It gets tricky in that the set will contain 312 members, but there will be six duplicates of each symbol/character.

Also i am looking to assign each of these symbols/characters a secondary value that will add, subtract, or do nothing to, a running count.

My question is, being very new to bash scripting, what commands/functions do this without errors from there being so many duplicate symbols, and how can i make it so that when i pass the symbol to the script, it does the operation of moving from set 1 to set2, and simultaneously the counter function as well?

So summing up my question for easy answering, what commands/functions are useful in this endeavor, how can the set member identity redundancy issue be circumvented, and if any what issues do you think i will run into with the dual function user input read?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? Because Bash is a terrible language for set manipulation, not least because it doesn't even have a set data type. Python, Ruby, Java or even Perl would be better suited for this.

Comment: Be warned most casinos will throw you out if they suspect you are "counting" .. :o)

Comment: I can figure out how to obscure my counting. im actually halfway done this script and anyone who wants it and my "methods" for detection avoidance are welcome to them.